# Typescript: Unexpected any. Which type for axios response?

Tags: typescript, axios

I have the following working code:

```
private async sendRequest <T = any>
  (url: AxiosRequestConfig['url'], data: AxiosRequestConfig['data'], method: AxiosRequestConfig['method']) 
  : Promise<{ data: T}> {
    this.log?.debug('Sending HTTPS %s request to %s - Header: %s.', method, url, JSON.stringify(data.header));
    const response = await this.instance({
      url,
      data,
      method,
    });
```

and the response is i.e. used like this:

```
const {data} = await this.sendRequest(
        this.uri,
        {},
        'GET',
      );

      this.log?.debug('App token: ', data.result.token);
```

Which type do I need use to prevent the warning for using <T = **any**>?

**Edit:**
Is there a "general" axios response type?
How do I find out?
The response is "usually" a nested json and axios serves it as java object, right?

Comment: The type of your response body

Comment: Thank you @Evert for your general answer. I've edited my question for clarification.

Comment: There is no general response type because it depends on what the server sends back. The most appropriate is probably the 'unknown' type if you have no advance idea of what you might get back.